# Show results based on existence or not of similar results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if SQL can so this, or quite how to ask it. I'm trying to include results if similar results are available or not:

```
L#  ORDER   LINE  PART       STATUS
------------------------------------
1   005478   1    XB3-001      0
2   005478   1    XB3-001      1
3   005478   1    XB3-001      2
4   005478   2    W3000        0
5   005478   2    W3000        1
6   005478   2    W3000        2
7   005489   1    1734-IB8     0
8   005489   1    1734-IB8     1
9   005489   2    1756-L7      0
10  005489   2    1756-L7      1
11  005489   2    1756-L7      2
```

I do a query for order number and some other things to filter results. What I would like to do, is display all lines for a "part" if an entry has a 0 and a 1, but not a 2.

So in the data above, only L# 7 and 8 should be returned.

I've been pondering it for hours, but I'm not coming up with anything good.

The actual query returns 12 columns, but the other columns aren't really relevant except to negate any grouping solutions. I do join a couple of tables with a left join, but that will likely change depending on a solution to this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Not exists` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.order = t.order and t2.part = t.part and t2.status = 2);
```

If you want to insist that both `0` and `1` are available, then let's enhance the logic:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.order = t.order and t2.part = t.part and t2.status = 2) and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.order = t.order and t2.part = t.part and t2.status = 0) and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.order = t.order and t2.part = t.part and t2.status = 1);
```

Or, if the status is only 0, 1, and 2 and there are no duplicates and status 1 implies that status 0 is there, then you could also do:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1 = (select max(status)
           from t t2
           where t2.order = t.order and t2.part = t.part
          );
```

Another method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order, part) as num_status_2
      from t
     ) t
where num_status_2 = 0;
```

or:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             sum(case when status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order, part) as num_status_0,
             sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order, part) as num_status_1,
             sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order, part) as num_status_2
      from t
     ) t
where num_status_2 = 0 and num_status_1 > 0 and num_status_2 > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select *
  from my_table
  where "PART" not in (
      select "PART"
        from my_table
        where status = 2
      )
    and "PART" in (
      select "PART"
        from my_table
        where status = 0
      )
    and "PART" in (
      select "PART"
        from my_table
        where status = 1
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of NOT and [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function would be what I would use here.
the exists function will match if rows exist and the NOT clause just flips the condition. Using the exists function like this will only return records where no record matching the criteria exists in the subquery.

```
select *
from Table t1
where not exists (
    select ''
    from Table t2
    where t1.order = t2.order
        and t1.part = t2.part
        and t2.status = 2
    )
    and t1.status IN (1, 0)
```